# CiviCRM - Mailpoet plugin conflict with Html2Text

Tags: civicontribute, civireport, php, receipts

We upgraded CiviCRM to the most recent version back in November and had the problem in the related ticket with ANY report failing when ANY filter was enabled. The error was:

Error thrown

Call to undefined method Html2Text\Html2Text::getText()

Another user reported finding this was a conflict with MailPoet (newsletter plugin) and we confirmed same.  We had a workaround available in that the newsletter is only active for part of the month, so we deactivated MailPoet plugin when we needed to run reports.

Unfortunately, we didn't notice that it also affected the automatic (& manual) issuing of receipt emails with the same issue/error.  I've spent the evening manually sending 100 email receipts. This isn't viable to continue. MailPoet is at latest version, CiviCRM is currently running 5.55.0 on a Wordpress install running 6.1.1. Issue present with PHP 7.4 & also after updated to 8.1

[Related to this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42921/reports-failing-after-upgrade-whenany-filter-enabled)

Comment: Unfortuntely, this fix was overwritten when MailPoet is upgraded. I can put it back in place, but it will keep happening and again I'm back to manually issuing the receipts that weren't sent. These two plugins worked with each other for the past 8 years. Is it a CiviCRM issue or MailPoet issue that I need to raise a bug with please?

Answer (score 1):

We managed to fix it by replacing the Html2Text\Html2Text with Civi version.

```
cd wp-content/plugins/mailpoet/vendor/soundasleep/html2text/src

cp ../../../../../civicrm/civicrm/vendor/html2text/html2text/src/Html2Text.php .
```

Comment: Thanks @Pradeep - will try this.  This changed hasn't affected anything in MailPoet for you?

Comment: so far its working fine

Comment: Thank you. That has it sorted for now anyway.